# Как преобразовать строки из файла в словарь в Python

Tags: python, строки, словарь

В фале task_5_6.txt находятся вот такие строки:
Физика: 30(л) - 20(лаб) - 10(пр)
Физкультура: - 30(пр) -
Химия: - 25(лаб) - 20(пр)
Нужно эти строки преобразовать в словарь, где ключем будут предметы, а значениями сумма часов.
Для вышеприведенного примера словарь должен выглядеть так
{Физика: 60, Физкультура: 30, Химия: 45}
Я решил задачу так:

```
with open('task_5_6.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    dict_list = file_out.readlines()
    lst_1 = []
    for el in dict_list:
        el = el.replace('(л)','')
        el = el.replace('-', '')
        el = el.replace('(пр)', '')
        el = el.replace('(лаб)','')
        lst_1.append(el)
    lst_1 = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(),lst_1))
    lst_2 = []
    for el in lst_1:
        el = el.split()
        m = sum([int(x) for x in el[1:]])
        del el[1:]
        el.append(m)
        for n in el:
            lst_2.append(n)
    dict_end = {lst_2[i]:lst_2[i+1] for i in range(0, len(lst_2), 2)}
    print(dict_end)
```

Но мне кажется, что код очень громоздкий. Если можете, подскажите, где я лишнего или туповатого наворотил

Comment: На stack overflow принято оставлять свои попытки решения, пожалуйста, прикрепите их, это можно сделать с помощью кнопки [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Все равно не понял, как выглядит список (а код вообще понять невозможно), но если так

```
Физика: 30(л) - 20(лаб) - 10(пр)
Физкультура: - 30(пр) -
Химия: - 25(лаб) - 20(пр)
```

то регулярками все решается просто

```
import re

result = {}

with open('task_5_6.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, rawvalue = line.split(':')
        hours = sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", rawvalue)))
        result[key] = hours
print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Огромное спасибо!